# Mac Terminal -bash: rbenv: command not found

Tags: bash, terminal, rbenv

Every time I open terminal on my Mac, the following outputs:

```
-bash: rbenv: command not found
```

Any idea how to stop this from appearing as it's annoying?

cat .*profile result:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

Comment: try 'cat .*profile' and show us the results, there might be something in your profile that is attempting to run rbenv but cant find it.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios I've added the results to the OP.

Comment: ... delete the lines containing `rbenv`?

Comment: @melpomene Just lines 3-5 or that whole block? What does it currently mean/how would it have got there?

Comment: `rbenv` is the Ruby environment setup.